# My program reads first name then last name in separately , while I need it to read first and last name together java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My program is for a voting system and the voting ballots have the candidate's first and last names. I am testing out just printing the information from the file but it separates the name of the candidates by spaces and not separate votes.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class readFile {
   private Scanner x;
   public void openFile() {
       try {
           x = new Scanner (new File("SmallListBallots.txt"));
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("could not find file");
       }   
   }
   public void readfile () {
       while(x.hasNext()) {
           String a =x.next();
           String b =x.next();
           String c =x.next();
           String d =x.next();
           
           System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s \n", a,b,c,d);
       }
   }
   public void closefile() {
       x.close();
   }
}
```

the text that is being read in:

```
VoterID First Choice    Second Choice   Third Choice

1001    Dalinar Kholin  Jasnah Kholin   Renarin Kholin

1002    Dalinar Kholin  Jasnah Kholin   Kaladin Stormblessed

1003    Torol Sadeas    Meridas Amaram  Shallan Davar
```

The program currently displays

```
1001 Dalinar Kholin Jasnah 
Kholin Renarin Kholin 1002 
Dalinar Kholin Jasnah Kholin 
Kaladin Stormblessed 1003 Torol 
Sadeas Meridas Amaram Shallan 
Davar
```

My goal is to display their full name as one "vote"  and then code the rest of the program so that I can count how many votes each candidate got in the first round.
Goal output:

```
Dalinar Kholin  Jasnah Kholin   Renarin Kholin

Dalinar Kholin  Jasnah Kholin   Kaladin Stormblessed

Torol Sadeas    Meridas Amaram  Shallan Davar
```

Comment: Please share what do you expect.

Comment: Your file contains lines of 7 tokens each, but you are only reading 4 per line, and then doing nothing about the end of line.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```java
public void readfile () {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z|A-Z]+\\s[a-z|A-Z]+");
    while(x.hasNext()) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x.nextLine());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            stringBuilder.append(matcher.group());
            stringBuilder.append("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```